# Why isn't Wordpress media upload working in CPT options submenu?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type that I created and made a submenu for "options" that I'd like to have for the archive page and the single pages (like header text and banners). I've been able to get the text fields working fine, but I can't get the media upload button to work. It just does a normal submit. I followed tons of different tutorials but this one was the only one that got me 1 step from the final product.
https://mycyberuniverse.com/integration-wordpress-media-uploader-plugin-options-page.html

This is the code for the submenu, option group and fields. It's in /inc/settingsMenus/blog-settings.php

```
<?php
/*
  ================================================================================
  Blog Settings
  ================================================================================
 */
    /*
  ============================================================================
  Add sub menu page to the custom post type
  ============================================================================
    */
    function add_blog_settings_page(){
        add_submenu_page(
            'edit.php?post_type=blog',
            'Blog Options',
            'Options',
            'manage_options',
            'blog_settings',
            'blog_options_display'
        );
    }
    add_action( 'admin_menu', 'add_blog_settings_page' );

    /*
  ========================================================================
  Options page callback
  ========================================================================
    */
    function blog_options_display(){
        echo '<div>';
        echo '<h1>Blog Options</h1>'; 
        echo '<form action="options.php" method="post">';
        settings_fields( 'blog_option_group' );
        do_settings_sections( 'blog_settings' );
        submit_button();
        echo '</form></div>';
    }

    /*
  ========================================================================
  Register and add settings
  ========================================================================
    */
    function blog_sub_menu_page_init(){
    //misha_add_options_page(); 

            register_setting(
            'blog_option_group', // Option group
            'blog_option_group', // Option name
            'blog_sanitize' // sanitize
        );

        add_settings_section(
            'header_settings_section', // ID
            'Archive Page Settings', // Title
            'blog_print_section_info', // Callback
            'blog_settings' // Page
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'archiveBlueTitle', // ID
            'Archive Blue Title', // Title
            'archiveBlueTitle_callback', // Callback
            'blog_settings', // Page
            'header_settings_section' // Section
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'archiveRedTitle', // ID
            'Archive Red Title', // Title
            'archiveRedTitle_callback', // Callback
            'blog_settings', // Page
            'header_settings_section' // Section
        );

        add_settings_field(
            'archiveBannerImage', // ID
            'Archive Banner Image', // Title
            'archiveBannerImage_callback', // Callback
            'blog_settings', // Page
            'header_settings_section' // Section
        );

    }
    add_action( 'admin_init', 'blog_sub_menu_page_init' );

    /*
  ========================================================================
  Sanitize each setting field as needed
  ========================================================================
 *
 * @param array $input Contains all settings fields as array keys
    */
    function blog_sanitize( $input ){
        $new_input = array();

        if( isset( $input['archiveBlueTitle'] ) )
            $new_input['archiveBlueTitle'] = sanitize_text_field( $input['archiveBlueTitle'] );

        if (isset($input['archiveRedTitle']))
            $new_input['archiveRedTitle'] = sanitize_text_field($input['archiveRedTitle']);

        if( isset( $input['archiveBannerImage'] ) )
            $new_input['archiveBannerImage'] = absint( $input['archiveBannerImage'] );

        return $new_input;
    }

    /*
  ========================================================================
  Print the Section text
  ========================================================================
    */
    function blog_print_section_info(){
        echo '<p>The settings for the Blog archive page.</p>';
    }

    /*
  ========================================================================
  Get the settings option array and print one of its values
  ========================================================================
    */
    function archiveBlueTitle_callback(){
        $mypage_options = get_option('blog_option_group');
        echo '<p>The first half of the page title (styled in blue).</p>';
        echo '<input id="archiveBlueTitle_string" name="blog_option_group[archiveBlueTitle]" type="text" value="' . $mypage_options["archiveBlueTitle"] . '" />';
    }

    /*
  ========================================================================
  Get the settings option array and print one of its values
  ========================================================================
    */
    function archiveRedTitle_callback() {
        $mypage_options = get_option('blog_option_group');
        echo '<p>The second half of the page title (styled in red).</p>';
        echo '<input id="archiveRedTitle_string" name="blog_option_group[archiveRedTitle]" type="text" value="' . $mypage_options["archiveRedTitle"] . '" />';
    }

    /*


     ========================================================================
        Get the settings option array and print one of its values
========================================================================
        */
        function archiveBannerImage_callback() {
            // Save attachment ID
            echo '<p>The banner image used at the top of the page.</p>';

            arthur_image_uploader('blog_option_group', 'archiveBannerImage', $width = 115, $height = 115);
    }
   /*
    ============================================================================
    Blog Settings
    ============================================================================
    */
    require_once('inc/settingsMenus/blog-settings.php');
            ?>
```

And this is the code for the media uploader and enqueuing all the needed files

```
/*
================================================================================
Enqueue media uploader and scripts
================================================================================
*/

/**
 * Load scripts and style sheet for settings page
 */
function arthur_load_scripts_admin() {

    // WordPress library
    wp_enqueue_media();

}
add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'arthur_load_scripts_admin' );

/*
================================================================================
Media Uploader function
================================================================================
*/
/**
 * Image Uploader
 * 
 * author: Arthur Gareginyan www.arthurgareginyan.com
 */
function arthur_image_uploader( $option_id, $field_id, $width, $height ) {

    // Set variables
    $options = get_option( $option_id );
    $default_image = 'http://www.freeiconspng.com/uploads/no-image-icon-15.png';

    if ( !empty( $options[$field_id] ) ) {
        $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $options[$field_id], array( $width, $height ) );
        $src = $image_attributes[0];
        $value = $options[$field_id];
    } else {
        $src = $default_image;
        $value = '';
    }

    $text = __( 'Upload', RSSFI_TEXT );

    // Print HTML field
    echo '
        <div class="upload">
            <img data-src="' . $default_image . '" src="' . $src . '" width="' . $width . 'px" height="' . $height . 'px" />
            <div>
                <input type="hidden" name="' . $option_id . '[' . $field_id . ']" id="' . $option_id . '[' . $field_id . ']" value="' . $value . '" />
                <button type="submit" class="upload_image_button button">' . $text . '</button>
                <button type="submit" class="remove_image_button button">&times;</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    ';
}


////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_myuploadscript_script');
function enqueue_myuploadscript_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script('myuploadscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/myuploadscript.js', array('jquery'));
}
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

And finally the javascript for the upload and remove buttons (in /js/myuploadscript.js)

```
/**
 * Image Uploader
 *
 * author: Arthur Gareginyan www.arthurgareginyan.com
 * Modified by Andy Warren - Original here: https://mycyberuniverse.com/integration-wordpress-media-uploader-plugin-options-page.html
**/

// The "Upload" button
jQuery('.upload_image_button').click(function() {
    var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
    var button = jQuery(this);
    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
        jQuery(button).parent().prev().attr('src', attachment.url);
        jQuery(button).prev().val(attachment.id);
        wp.media.editor.send.attachment = send_attachment_bkp;
    }
    wp.media.editor.open(button);
    return false;
});

// The "Remove" button (remove the value from input type='hidden')
jQuery('.remove_image_button').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault(); // Added this to prevent remove button submitting and refreshing page when clicked
    var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
    if (answer == true) {
        var src = jQuery(this).parent().prev().attr('data-src');
        jQuery(this).parent().prev().attr('src', src);
        jQuery(this).prev().prev().val('');
    }
    return false;
});
```

The result is I have the following page. The text fields work fine but when I click the "Upload" button, it just submits the form and no javascript is triggered.

[Screenshot of CPT Options page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HevR4.png)

Help me out here guys. I'm not an expert by any means but as far as I can see, this should be working fine right? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I finally found it! A newbie mistake to make, I didn't put my jQuery code inside `$(document).ready(function() {});` , so even though my code was correct, the listeners were never set up.

Below is the final javascript code. I thought I'd answer the question so if anyone has this problem they don't face days of grief over 2 lines of code like I did.

```
/**
 * Image Uploader
 *
 * author: Arthur Gareginyan www.arthurgareginyan.com
 * Modified by Andy Warren - Original here: https://mycyberuniverse.com/integration-wordpress-media-uploader-plugin-options-page.html
**/

// The "Upload" button
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.upload_image_button').click(function() {
            var send_attachment_bkp = wp.media.editor.send.attachment;
            var button = jQuery(this);
            wp.media.editor.send.attachment = function(props, attachment) {
                    jQuery(button).parent().prev().attr('src', attachment.url);
                    jQuery(button).prev().val(attachment.id);
                    wp.media.editor.send.attachment = send_attachment_bkp;
            }
            wp.media.editor.open(button);
            return false;
    });

    // The "Remove" button (remove the value from input type='hidden')
    jQuery('.remove_image_button').click(function(event) {
            event.preventDefault(); // Added this to prevent remove button submitting and refreshing page when clicked
            var answer = confirm('Are you sure?');
            if (answer == true) {
                    var src = jQuery(this).parent().prev().attr('data-src');
                    jQuery(this).parent().prev().attr('src', src);
                    jQuery(this).prev().prev().val('');
            }
            return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to hide the actions panel on the left?